# Getting "�" in HTML content

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

I have simple web page with some description, where its data is coming from mysql database and I am showing it using PHP, but some where in description I am getting "�" symbol between two words.
I have tried htmlentities and htmlspecialchars, but anything is not working, last I removed charset='utf-8' from meta tag, then it's working. But it is compulsory to use.

So, How can I get rid of "�" in my description?

Comment: Is it possible that either your PHP code was copied and pasted from somewhere else, or the data in your database was? Try manually retyping your PHP code on the problem line and try updating a problem table row manually with new data to see if your problem is fixed.

Comment: You have a character that doesn't match the charset. Have you ever seen a quote `"` but it looks like it's italic, but it wasn't, it was just a messed up character. Normally this happens with data from people of other regions, inserting data, then you print it on your page. You shouldn't remove the meta charset tag. Look at the data, where your getting the weird symbol, and you probably have a messed up character. Even if your not sure, remove the character, and put it back yourself.

Comment: try to add : AddDefaultCharset utf-8 in your .htaccess file

Comment: yes, I have copied data from one site, and insert into database, but I have more than 1500 descriptions that I copied. so it is difficult to retype it manually? is there any other solution?

Comment: � is valid text that indicates a point where data was lost due to mis-identifying the source encoding during a conversion. Ideally, you would go back and get it the right way. Removing the charset meta tag is probably resulting in further data loss—only it happens to made the results look prettier.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` (to see what is stored); Do you have a `meta` tag in the html?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.Use following php inbuilt function to avoid those characters on given string. In your case, data from database.

```
html_entity_decode($given_string,ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
```